# Вывод values в Map в зависимости от ввода пользователя

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Есть `LinkedHashMap`, вот часть для примера:

```java
public class Codec {
    public Map<String, String> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public void putData() {
        dataMap.put("affect", "влиять");
        dataMap.put("after", "после");
        dataMap.put("again", "опять");
        dataMap.put("against", "против");
        dataMap.put("age", "возраст");
    }
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил слово, или несколько за один ввод, на английском, а программа выдавала на русском. Я написал класс с методом, который делает это с одним словом:

```java
public class Do {
    Codec codec = new Codec();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    public void encode() {
        codec.putData();
        if (codec.dataMap.containsKey(s)) {
            System.out.println("ввод пользователя" + " " + s);
            System.out.println("Ответ" + " " + codec.dataMap.get(s));
        } else {
            System.out.println("try one more time");

        }
    }
}
```

```
Ввод пользователя: age
Ответ: возраст
```

Но я не могу понять, как это правильно сделать с несколькими словами ввода. Извиняюсь заранее, если это простой вопрос, так как только учусь и могу не понимать элементарных вещей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте разобраться для начала с этим кодом. 
Не забывайте про правила именования переменых и методов, а так же про инкапсуляцию.
Удачи

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Codec {

    private final Map<String, String> DATA;

    public Codec() {
        this.DATA = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        DATA.put("affect", "влиять");
        DATA.put("after", "после");
        DATA.put("again", "опять");
        DATA.put("against", "против");
        DATA.put("age", "возраст");
    }

    public String execute (String userInput) {
        return Arrays.stream(userInput.toLowerCase().split(" "))
                .map(t->DATA.getOrDefault(t.trim(), "*"))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Do {

    private final static Codec CODEC = new Codec();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInput = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        String result = CODEC.execute(userInput);
        System.out.println("Ввод пользователя : " + userInput);
        System.out.println("Ответ : " + result);
    }

}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, все работает=) с лямбдой все красиво вышло, правда не для меня еще все понятно (знаний немного не хватает), но буду разбираться по ходу дела.